# Clipboard data sort in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have a form in which I need to sort text from the clipboard into the appropriate fields. Essentially, I copy a customer email, click a button on the form, and it will read the data and put the info into the fields. There are several fields, such as the customer's name, the company's name, the telephone number, whether they have a support plan.

All emails are formatted in the same way (apart from the random spaces which I have no control of) and are used by several employees:

Company:                   TEST LTD

Customer's name:     Joe Johnson

Department:           IT Operations Manager

Customer's phone:     012345678910

Customer's email:       JOE.JOHNSON@TEST.COM

Instrument:                   SUP

Serial Number:             EM2PC2938C

Coverage:             Plan No Warranty

So, my question is:

I need to be able to copy this text straight from an email, click on a button that will look through the text in the clipboard, and put the different pieces of information into different text boxes labelled the same as in the email, but without the identifier (such as 'Email:' or 'Coverage'), so essentially anything after the colon goes into the textbox.

I have some code to get the data and put into into a rich text box which I planned to use to sort the data (I know I can do it straight from code, but didn't know how to)

```
rtbx_ClipboardData.text = Clipboard.GetText
```

And some code to remove any text before the colon:

```
tbx_Data_Company.Text = rtbx_ClipboardData.Text.Substring(rtbx_ClipboardData.Text.IndexOf(":") + 1)
```

This code works but I need to do it several times and put data into the appropriate fields which is where I am struggling.

If anyone could suggest anything/provide some sample code I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.Substring` and `.IndexOf`, I would use `String.Split`.

Get the string from the clip board and split it into lines removing any empty lines. Take each element of the resulting array (one line) and split that by the colon. We want the second element of this array (1) trimmed of any leading or trailing spaces and assigned to the appropriate text box. Then repeat with each line.

```
Private Sub GetFieldsFromEmail()
    Dim eText As String = Clipboard.GetText()
    Dim lines = eText.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    txtCompany.Text = lines(0).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    txtName.Text = lines(1).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    txtDepartment.Text = lines(2).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    txtPhone.Text = lines(3).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    txtEmail.Text = lines(4).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    txtInstrument.Text = lines(5).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    txtSerNum.Text = lines(6).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    txtCoverage.Text = lines(7).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

If there is random text before and after...

```
Private Sub GetFieldsFromEmail()
    Dim eText As String = Clipboard.GetText()
    Dim lines = eText.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim StartLine As Integer
    For i = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        If lines(i).StartsWith("Company") Then
            StartLine = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    TextBox18.Text = lines(StartLine).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    TextBox19.Text = lines(StartLine + 1).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    TextBox20.Text = lines(StartLine + 2).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    TextBox21.Text = lines(StartLine + 3).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    TextBox22.Text = lines(StartLine + 4).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    TextBox23.Text = lines(StartLine + 5).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    TextBox24.Text = lines(StartLine + 6).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
    TextBox25.Text = lines(StartLine + 7).Split(":"c)(1).Trim
End Sub
```

I just added a For loop to find where to start reading the data. Tested by copying several paragraphs before and after your data directly from your question. I changed the names of the text boxes to match what I had available.

Comment: that works, but it doesn't check the text before hand and put it into the right field. The email is roughly the same layout however there is text before and after this text and when pasting an email in it just looked for colons, not the info such as 'Company: '. If you could help add this it would be great.

Comment: @JoshF98 The only information I have is what is in your question. I copied the text from your question and it all went into the correct fields. If your requirements are different than what you showed please include the correct sample data in your question.

Comment: there is normally some text that the customer/employee puts before the email, such as a transcript. I'm sorry if I'd made this confusing. I tried your code, but it's not doing anything, what could be the reason? It doesn't throw an error, but it doesn't put the text in the text box?

Comment: Are you sure there is something on the clipboard? Add a line after `Dim eText As String = Clipboard.GetText()` Debug.Print(eText). Check your immediate window after you run the program.

Comment: Still no joy. Nothing happens. Debug window shows the data I had in the clipboard and it has the right info.

Comment: Can you put a break point and and step through the code? We may be moved to chat.