# Clipboard data sort - Colon sorting issue

Tags: vb.net

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272032/clipboard-data-sort-in-vb-net) on Stack Overflow a few days ago asking for a solution for copying email support forms and pasting the data into the appropriate text fields on a form. I got an answer which solved my problem - until I went to go use the tool and realized a problem.

I am using this code:

```
'Service Plan Description
For i = 0 To lines.Count - 1
    If lines(i).StartsWith("Service Plan Desc. :") Then
        StartLine = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
tbx_ServicePlanDescription.Text = lines(StartLine).Split(":"c)(1).Trim 'Put sorted data into textbox
```

And when I copy the following text into the clipboard to test the Service Plan textbox:

Maint:AbloEnterprise S/W AddOn (5)

It only pastes 'Maint' in the textbox because the code purposely removes the colons.

So my question is: What would be a way to overcome this?

Comment: If you are asking how to split the line at only the first colon, then you can use the [`Split(Char[], Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_) method, as in `lines(StartLine).Split({":"c}, 2)(1).Trim()`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the [`Split(Char[], Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_StringSplitOptions_) method to limit how many parts the split would split the string into, as suggested in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60364567/clipboard-data-sort-colon-sorting-issue#comment106783061_60364567), like this:

```
tbx_ServicePlanDescription.Text = lines(StartLine).Split({":"c}, 2)(1).Trim()
```